# Saving object to another collection in beforeUpdate?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm working on archival functionality in my grails application.

My aim is everytime I do an update I save the current state to another collection and update the previous state.

Is this possible? I'm having trouble as the POGO won't save as its not serializable. I'd rather not implement the serializable class as I may be restricted from it.

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    def currentState = this
            getDB().archives.insert(currentState)

}
```

THe error I'm getting complains that the class is not serializable. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?